Least squares polynomial of degree 2
Question:

Population growth in imaginary districts is described by the following table. Use the least-square polynomial of degree $2$ to predict populations for the year $2000$.
$$\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrr} \text {District} & 1950 & 1960 & 1965 & 1970 & 1975 & 1980 & 1983 & 1984 \\ \hline \text {1} & 554 & 801 & 873 & 984 & 1102 & 1183 & 1225 & 1239 \\ \text {2} & 84 & 94 & 99 & 104 & 112 & 117 & 119 & 119 \\ \text {3} & 122 & 135 & 143 & 148 & 152 & 154 & 154 & 154 \\ \text {4} & 166 & 199 & 214 & 227 & 239 & 252 & 259 & 261 \\ \text {5} & 2504 & 3014 & 3324 & 3683 & 4076 & 4453 & 4685 & 4763 \end{array}$$

I'm becoming very frustrated with this question. I can't seem to calculate the coefficients correctly. Can I use the line of best fit for polynomials on excel? By doing that I got $y=-0.1136x^2+24.112x+555.61$ for district $1$. I've also tried to solve it by using the equation $Mv=y$ where $M$ is the polynomial matrix and $v$ are the coefficients. I understand how to do the question once I have the coefficients though. Thank you in advance!

Welcome to math SE. Use mathjax instead of a picture.

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! For more approximation or accuracy, I used excel to calculate automatically the best line fit for district 1 and the quadratic equation was the most accurate one.

The equation I got (for district 1 only) was $y = -12.03x^2 +203.07x+388.09$.

If you use the given years as input to your model, the model is $-0.1136 x^2 + 467.1 x - 478460$ and you would specialize to $x = 2000$ to get the predicted population in 2000.  If you shift the years down by 1950, so the first input datum is $0$, the model is $-0.1136 x^2 + 24.11 x + 555.613$ and you specialize to $x = 2000-1950 = 50$ to get the predicted population in that district.

Elaborating on @EricTowers' comment: $$a {\left( x - \xi \right)}^{2} + b \left( x - \xi \right) + c = a {x}^{2} + \left( b - 2 a \xi \right) x + (c - b \xi + a {\xi}^{2})$$ where $\xi = 1950$.
